# Trouble adding to an ArrayList of ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi all I'm having trouble at the moment with one of my methods at the moment.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<UnigramLanguageModel>> arrayListReadCategoriesDC() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line="";

    ArrayList<ArrayList<UnigramLanguageModel>> dcx = new ArrayList<ArrayList<UnigramLanguageModel>>();
    ArrayList<UnigramLanguageModel> ulm = new ArrayList<UnigramLanguageModel>();

    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\mccluskm\\Desktop\\trainingSet\\"+dcP[i]+"\\"+dc[i]+".txt"));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            String[] split = line.split(":");
            ulm.add(new UnigramLanguageModel(split[0],Integer.parseInt(split[1]),true));
        }
        //System.out.println("Adding stage: "+ulm.size());
        dcx.add(ulm);
        //System.out.println("From within nested ArrayList: "+dcx.get(i).size());
        ulm.clear();
    }
    br.close();
    return dcx;
}
```

Here is my method where I read in from various files (which represent different categories). Each category gets its own ArrayList and then I want to return an ArrayList>

From within the main method I call it like this:

```
UnigramLanguageModel ulm = new UnigramLanguageModel ();
ArrayList<ArrayList<UnigramLanguageModel>> dc =ulm.arrayListReadCategoriesDC();
```

It returns an empty an arraylist holding 7 empty arraylists and I dont know why?
If anyone could help I would really appreciate it!

Comment: `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){ String[] split = line.split(":"); ulm.add(new UnigramLanguageModel(split[0],Integer.parseInt(split[1]),true)); } ` need to check this code part. Please check if underlying .txt file gets seperated properly with : seperator.     Seven arraylists got added into another arraylist because of  `dcx.add(ulm);`

Comment: I have checked the file is read correctly and the individual elements are added to the Object correctly. Yeh I am just curious as to why it is adding empty ArrayLists despite me populating them above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your problem.
Please remove `ulm.clear();` call from your code. This will solves your problem.

Morover declaring something like below is not good approach-

```
ArrayList<UnigramLanguageModel> ulm = new ArrayList<UnigramLanguageModel>();
```

Try instead below--

```
List<UnigramLanguageModel> ulm = new ArrayList<UnigramLanguageModel>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be you are inserting the same reference into the topmost array list always. Instead of using `ulm.clear`, create a new ulm object in the loop. That should resolve the issue.